# Can the youyeetooX1 bios, support any M.2 to SATA3.0 conversion card?

Tags: ssd, bios, motherboard, sata

Obviously, using a M.2 to SATA3.0 conversion card  (JMB585 or ASM1166 based) would allow to build a NAS from a youyeetoo X1 motherboard.

Did any one manage to do that and would you know if it might be possible, possibly by setting BIOS options?

I no longer try to boot a hard drive plugged on the conversion card since @JMY1000 explained that an OS should be started first.

I boot Ubuntu from another (USB) drive. The convertion card is blinking blue at start but lights then turns off. The SATA drive simply plugged on the conversion card seems not recognised by the OS.

Would you know where in the BIOS it is possible to see if the card is recognized?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! As written this seems to be a question regarding a technical support request for existing hardware, rather than a recommendation for new hardware; as such, this is probably better suited for Super User rather than Hardware Recs. That said, in my experience drives attached to ASM1166-based M.2 adapter don't typically show up in the BIOS, they'll only show up once booted into the OS (assuming that the OS has proper support.) What OS are you using, and are you getting any error message there?

Comment: @JMY1000 , I was trying to boot the os from a drive attached to the ASM1166-based M.2 adapter. The OS is last Debian, I will try to boot it from another drive visible from the bios then. Thanks

Comment: "Using a M.2 to SATA3.0 conversion card (JMB585 or ASM1166 based) would allow to build a NAS from a youyeetoo X1 motherboard." - Is this a statement or a question?

Comment: A statement. How should I avoid any ambiguity ? @JoepvanSteen

Comment: some more information might be useful - from the livedisk, it might be worth checking if the card itself is picked up - lshw is useful for seeing what you have detected, and dmesg can be useful for detecting issues.